# gameObject out of screen edge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, 2d

I have this piece of code from my 2D game character. It's working fine on respawning my character on random Screen positions, but the problem is that this code works with my game caharacter Center, I mean it generates the center position to a Random Range and there on the edge of the screen my chracter is going half out of the screen... I need this code working on any Android device and i dont know how i can solve this. Anyone a simple solution?

Sorry for my beginner english.

```
//Generate Random X
    float generateX()
    {
        float x = Random.Range(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0, 0)).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width, 0)).x);
        return x;
    }

    //Generate Random Y
    float generateY()
    {
        float y = Random.Range(2.0f, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0, Screen.height)).y);
        return y;
    }

void generateCoordinates()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(generateX(), generateY());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your 2D character is a sprite it must have a sprite renderer component. You could get its bounds with:

```
Bounds bounds = transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds;
```

and you could edit your code like:

```
float generateX()
{
    float x = Random.Range(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0, 0)).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width, 0)).x);
    //add/remove extents to x value to keep sprite in bounds of screen
    if(x < 0) 
        x += bounds.max.x;
    else 
        x -= bounds.max.x;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: After operating your code my character sometimes spawns totally out of the screen. I mean next to the Screen. Idk why ...

Comment: I changed "bounds.max.x/min.x" to "bounds.extents.x" and now it is Working fine. Thank you :)

Comment: I was about to say change min to max :) but extents would also do. You're welcome